# Ошибка при использовании yt-dl. YouTube_dl.utils.RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id

Tags: python, discord.py, youtube-dl

Написал код для дискорд бота, который воспроизводит аудио из YouTube. Но при воспроизведении возникает ошибка `youtube_dl.utils.RegexNotFoundError: Unable to extract uploader id;`
Вот блок кода, где применяю yt_dl:

````
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, arg):
    global vc
    try:
        voice_channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        vc = await voice_channel.connect()
    except:
        await ctx.send(
            '```\nля-ля-ля тополя \n```')
    if vc.is_playing():
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, музыка уже проигрывается.')
    else:
        with YoutubeDL(yt_dl_opt) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(arg, download=False)
        url = info['formats'][0]['url']
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="адрес на ffmpeg", source=url, **ffmpeg_opt))
        while vc.is_playing() or vc.is_paused():
            await sleep(1)
        await vc.disconnect()
````

Все библиотеки установлены.
Помогите, пожалуйста.